# Desktop doesn't come up after installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64x with Live USB as my CD ROM isn't working. The Live USB was made in Windows (no errors came while doing so). I then installed the 12.04 from USB with everything OK. In the end it asked for reboot I did that and removed USB too. Upon reboot my system hangs on black screen with only a black '_' blinking.

But when I put USB back in and then reboot, username / password login screen does come up but as soon as I login the whole system becomes unstable and I can't even see the Unity Launcher. I can create a folder but then it says some `missing libs` and whole system goes hung.

Comment: What do you mean by putting USB back in and rebooting ? Running ubuntu directly from bootable USB drive ?

Comment: Na, post installation w/o putting the USB in no screen comes up. I believe its a thing with my age old acer 4520 and ubuntu 12.04. I'm going for 11.10 to see if it works or not.

Comment: I have had the best exp with 10.10 on older machines. just saying.

Comment: @Abhinav why didn't you mention this hardware info in the question? Also, have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Have you booted from your USB drive, or just used Wubi (the Windows installer for Ubuntu) from your USB drive? Things like this usually happen when using (crappy) Wubi.

Comment: It seems like if I install it multiple times things do get better. Now the system only crashes in extreme cases (multiple windows + videos + music player an all). Will stick with 12.04 for now but really looking forward to someone checking on the crash reports i sent across.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your installation got corrupted somehow. What you would need to do is reinstall, by reformatting the partition/drive (in Windows) with the corrupted installation and then installing again.

Comment: Thanks Taylor for the reply but the issue still persists.